# webuntis.errors.RemoteError: Request ID was not the same one as returned

Tags: python

can anyone help we with the webuntis api?
I used a standart code:

```py
import webuntis

s = webuntis.Session(
    username='Name',
    password='Password',
    server='klio.webuntis.com',
    school='Shool',
    useragent='WebUntis Test'
).login()

for klasse in s.klassen():
    print(klasse.name)
```

But its gives me following error:

```
  File "main.py", line 18, in <module>
    s = webuntis.Session(
  File "/home/bwlok/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/webuntis/session.py", line 91, in login
    res = self._request('authenticate', {
  File "/home/bwlok/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/webuntis/session.py", line 118, in _request
    data = rpc_request(self.config, method, params or {})
  File "/home/bwlok/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/webuntis/utils/remote.py", line 90, in rpc_request
    return _parse_result(request_body, result_body)
  File "/home/bwlok/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/webuntis/utils/remote.py", line 118, in _parse_result
    raise errors.RemoteError(
webuntis.errors.RemoteError: Request ID was not the same one as returned. 2021-09-22 18:43:23.684083 -- error
```

Does anyone know what I need to change?

Answer (score -1):

You need to add your Untis username and password. Also you need the correct School name.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).